# What led to the alternate definition of secularism in India?

Tags: india

I was reading [this post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/16196/35379) explaining how secularism is understood in India, it turns out that it is quite different from how it is understood in a dictionary/ in the west.

> In the West, the word secular implies three things: freedom of
> religion, equal citizenship to each citizen regardless of his or her
> religion, and the separation of religion and state.
>
> In contrast, in India, the word secular does not imply separation of
> religion and state. It means equal treatment of all religions.
> [...]
>
> The term secularism in India also differs from the French concept for
> secularity, namely laïcité.[33] While the French concept demands
> absence of governmental institutions in religion, as well as absence
> of religion in governmental institutions and schools; the Indian
> concept, in contrast, provides financial support to religious schools
> and accepts religious law over governmental institutions.
>
> Quoted from answer

My question is what political reasons/ historical reasons led to this redefinition?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128906/discussion-on-question-by-buraian-what-led-to-the-alternate-definition-of-secula).